# Best Practices for Managing Azure Secrets in Terraform CI/CD Pipelines

Tags: azure, terraform

I am looking for guidance on how to securely manage Azure Service principal when running Terraform from a CI/CD pipeline.
When I run Terraform locally, I use to pass them in this way

```yaml
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  subscription_id = "<my_subscription_id>"
  tenant_id       = "<my_tenant_id>"
}
```

but I'm not sure where to securely store them when using a CI/CD pipeline.

I have two main options in mind and would appreciate insights on the best practices:

1. Storing Terraform credentials as secrets within the pipeline variables?
2. Utilizing Azure Key Vault in some way

If the second option is recommended, what are the best practices and guidelines for integrating Azure Key Vault into Terraform workflows within a CI/CD pipeline?

I want to ensure the highest level of security while maintaining an efficient and scalable CI/CD process. Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: what type of secrets are you storing ?

Comment: I mean the Managed Identity or the Service Principal used by Terraform

Comment: you could use federated credentials for that so you need to store any secrets: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the second option is recommended, what are the best practices and guidelines for integrating Azure Key Vault into Terraform workflows within a CI/CD pipeline?

You can use `Azure Key Vault` to securely store the `Terraform` credentials it provides a centralized and secure way to manage sensitive information like `secrets` and `keys`.

Grant your `CI/CD` pipeline access to `Azure Key Vault` by creating an `Azure AD application` with a **Key Vault Administrator** role. Then, use the application's **client ID** and **client secret** to authenticate and retrieve Terraform credentials from the `Key Vault`.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
      alias           = "credentials"
      subscription_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.subscription_id.value
      tenant_id       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.tenant_id.value
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
    }
    data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      name                = "srikv05"
      resource_group_name = "Sri"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "subscription_id" {
      name         = "subscriptionid"
      key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }
    data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tenant_id" {
      name         = "tenantid"
      key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage_rg" {
      name     = "venkat-test-rg"
      location = "east us"
      provider = azurerm.credentials
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

This approach enables you to store `Terraform` credentials securely in your `CI/CD` pipeline using `Azure Key Vault's` advanced security features.